# 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I referred few help provided for the above error but could not solve.

I tried creating chat application with example provided in following url "http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2014/02/27/asp.net-signalr-building-a-simple-real-time-chat-application.aspx"

The code at cshtml is as below. Have only changed the js file as its there on my scripts folder. Please help me out with this

```
@section scripts{

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.2.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("/signalr/hubs")



<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        showModalUserNickName();
    });
    function showModalUserNickName() {

        $("#dialog").dialog({

            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    startChatHub();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    function startChatHub() {
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

        // Get the user name.
        $('#nickname').val($('#nick').val());
        chat.client.differentName = function (name) {
            showModalUserNickName();
            return false;
            // Prompts for different user name
            $('#nickname').val($('#nick').val());
            chat.server.notify($('#nickname').val(), $.connection.hub.id);
        };
        chat.client.online = function (name) {
            // Update list of users
            if (name == $('#nickname').val())
                $('#onlineusers').append('<div class="border" style="color:green">You: ' + name + '</div>');
            else {
                $('#onlineusers').append('<div class="border">' + name + '</div>');
                $("#users").append('<option value="' + name + '">' + name + '</option>');
            }
        };
        chat.client.enters = function (name) {
            $('#chatlog').append('<div style="font-style:italic;"><i>' + name + ' joins the conversation</i></div>');
            $("#users").append('<option value="' + name + '">' + name + '</option>');
            $('#onlineusers').append('<div class="border">' + name + '</div>');
        };
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast chat messages.
        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
            //Interpret smileys
            message = message.replace(":)", "<img src=\"/images/smile.gif\" class=\"smileys\" />");
            message = message.replace(":D", "<img src=\"/images/laugh.gif\" class=\"smileys\" />");
            message = message.replace(":o", "<img src=\"/images/cool.gif\" class=\"smileys\" />");

            //display the message
            $('#chatlog').append('<div class="border"><span style="color:orange">' + name + '</span>: ' + message + '</div>');
        };
        chat.client.disconnected = function (name) {
            //Calls when someone leaves the page
            $('#chatlog').append('<div style="font-style:italic;"><i>' + name + ' leaves the conversation</i></div>');
            $('#onlineusers div').remove(":contains('" + name + "')");
            $("#users option").remove(":contains('" + name + "')");
        }

        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            //Calls the notify method of the server
            chat.server.notify($('#nickname').val(), $.connection.hub.id);
            $('#btnsend').click(function () {
                if ($("#users").val() == "All") {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub.
                    chat.server.send($('#nickname').val(), $('#message').val());
                }
                else {
                    chat.server.sendToSpecific($('#nickname').val(), $('#message').val(), $("#users").val());
                }
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });

        });
    }
</script>
}







<div id="container">

    <input type="hidden" id="nickname" />
    <div id="chatlog"></div>
    <div id="onlineusers">
        <b>Online Users</b>
    </div>
    <div id="chatarea">
        <div class="messagelog">
            <textarea spellcheck="true" id="message" class="messagebox"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="actionpane">
            <input type="button" value="send" id="btnsend" />
        </div>

        <div class="actionpane">
            <select id="users">
                <option vaue="All">All</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dialog" title="Enter your name to start chat">
        <input type="text" id="nick" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't appear to have included `jquery-{version}.js`

Comment: where do we include jquery-{version}.js.  On webconfig under packages we  have 
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.8.2" targetFramework="net45" />

Comment: You need to include the file in the view (if its not already in the view or the layout) - in the first line after `@section scripts{` add `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`

Comment: my _layout file have added  

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js") and in bundleconfig.cs already has code 
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

Comment: The why have you included `jquery-ui` again in the view? (remove one or the other)

Comment: Still I get same error.

Comment: have removed @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.2.min.js") from view. Apart from that the same version is there as it was there at bundle file and have done no change in layout files apart from changes done earlier. Still getting same error. Am I doing some thing really wrong or am I missing. Please help me out.